# Collapse pandas multiindex to a single index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a multi-indexed Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

How can I merge the three-tiered index into one index? Namely, I want to turn (1987, 1, 2) into pd.datetime(1987, 1, 2). I'd prefer a vectorized approach using df.index.map. Here's code that can create the top part of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'3 months': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
    index=[
        [1987, 1987, 1987, 1987,1987],
        [1,1,1,1,1],
        [2,5,6,7,8]
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest solution with `pd.Index.map`

```
df.set_index(df.index.map(lambda t: pd.datetime(*t)))

            3 months
1987-01-02         1
1987-01-05         2
1987-01-06         3
1987-01-07         4
1987-01-08         5
```

Comment: I was looking at your solution to a similar problem just a few minutes ago ... thank you!

Comment: np, glad I could help (-:

Answer (score 3):

pass to a dataframe

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame(df.index.values.tolist(), columns=['year','month','day']))
df
Out[669]: 
            3 months
1987-01-02         1
1987-01-05         2
1987-01-06         3
1987-01-07         4
1987-01-08         5
```