# Pandas: how to collapse a Series' MultiIndex to a DateTimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

As a followup of [Pandas groupby: group by semester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854809/pandas-groupby-group-by-semester) I need to collapse a Series' MultiIndex to a DateTimeIndex.

I already gave a look at [Collapse Pandas MultiIndex to Single Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431868/collapse-pandas-multiindex-to-a-single-index) but at no avail. I cannot make it work.

Series `ser` is:

```
dtime  dtime
2016   1        78.0
       7        79.0
2017   1        73.0
       7        79.0
2018   1        79.0
       7        71.0
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

How to collapse `dtime` to a single DateTimeIndex?

```
dtime
2016-01-01      78.0
2016-07-01      79.0
2017-01-01      73.0
2017-07-01      79.0
2018-01-01      79.0
2018-07-01      71.0
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

This is the code producing my demo Series `ser`:

```
from datetime import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
days = pd.date_range(start="2016-02-15", 
                     end="2018-09-12",
                    freq="2W")

df = pd.DataFrame({"dtime":days, "values":np.random.randint(50, high=80, size=len(days))}).set_index("dtime")

# group by semester
year = df.index.year.astype(int)
month = (df.index.month.astype(int) - 1) // 6 * 6 + 1
grouped = df.groupby([year, month])

ser = grouped.describe()[("values", "max")].rename("values")
print(ser)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need join levels of `MultiIndex` or `Series` together and convert to `datetimes`:

```
idx = ser.index.get_level_values(0).astype(str) +  ser.index.get_level_values(1).astype(str)

ser.index = pd.to_datetime(idx, format='%Y%m')
print(ser)
2016-01-01    78.0
2016-07-01    79.0
2017-01-01    73.0
2017-07-01    79.0
2018-01-01    79.0
2018-07-01    71.0
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

Or:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(year.astype(str) + month.astype(str), format='%Y%m')
grouped = df.groupby(dates)

ser = grouped.describe()[("values", "max")].rename("values")
print (ser)
2016-01-01    78.0
2016-07-01    79.0
2017-01-01    73.0
2017-07-01    79.0
2018-01-01    79.0
2018-07-01    71.0
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

Comment: how can you do it? I have been tinkering with this stuff for hours... I am really impressed! 
Thank you once more.