# How to chance DateTime multiindex back into normal DateTime index?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have two dataframes which their indexes different as shown below;

df1:

```
                 C1
   Y     M  D
    2020  5  1   5
             2   7
             3   34
             4   4
             5   98
```

df2

```
                C1 
    Date
    2020-5-6   2
    2020-5-7   11
    2020-5-8   15
    2020-5-9   3
    2020-5-10  8
```

Due to the way they were cleaned and grouped etc the index is in different formats.
I need to merge these dataframes together.

Is there anyway of simply converting the multiindex back to a single index?
Or can I merge them the way they are? I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help much appreciated!

[image: Dataframe 1]

[image: Dataframe 2]

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Pandas: how to collapse a Series' MultiIndex to a DateTimeIndex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857052/pandas-how-to-collapse-a-series-multiindex-to-a-datetimeindex) .. others searching with `python pandas multiindex with year month day to datetimeindex site:stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach which is cleaner than the linked question:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime([f'{y}-{m}-{d}' for y,m,d in df.index],
                          format='%Y-%m')
```

Output:

```
            C1
2020-05-01   5
2020-05-02   7
2020-05-03  34
2020-05-04   4
2020-05-05  98
```

**Note**: for Python 2.7, instead of `f'{y}-{m}-{d}'`, do

```
'{}-{}-{}'.format(y,m,d)
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to look like it will work but I'm getting a syntax error;
```
df.index = pd.to_datetime([f '{y}-{m}-{d}' for y,m,d in df.index], format='%Y-%m')
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is your version of python?

Comment: That works perfectly and very clean! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

We have the function `to_datetime` with correct name

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.rename_axis(['year','month','day']).index.to_frame())
df
Out[435]: 
            C1
2020-05-01   5
2020-05-02   7
2020-05-03  34
2020-05-04   4
2020-05-05  98
```